# Pip installing to the wrong directory in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip

I am creating a bunch of Python scripts to create some neural networks and I am trying to leverage GPU computing in the process. I have a Git repo with all my work and have been testing the code on both my local machine (Mac OS 10.14) and a server that I ssh into (Ubuntu 18.04). Developing on my local machine, everything is working fine, but pip is having an issue on the server side.

I start by issuing the commands:

```
> virtualenv automatic/venv
[virtualenv output]
> source automatic/venv/bin/activate
> which pip
.../automatic/venv/bin/pip
> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 47.3.1
wheel      0.34.2
```

where I included the `...` to obscure the directory location, but rest assured it's the correct location. I then run

```
> pip install numpy
[pip output]
> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
numpy      1.19.1
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 49.2.0
wheel      0.34.2
```

So pip installed exactly where it needed to install. Again, this is all on my local machine.

On the server I ssh into, the first set of commands all work and output the same. However, once I go to install numpy here, I get this

```
> pip install numpy
[pip output]
> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 47.3.1
wheel      0.34.2
```

and it turns out pip installed the package at `~/python/lib/site-packages` for some unknown reason. I also ran `printenv | grep -i py` to see if there were any environment variables messing with pip and I got

```
OLDPWD=...
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=...
```

where the outputs were not the home directory.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

**Edit** here is the output from running `pip install numpy`:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.19.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.5 MB 5.8 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.19.1
```

Comment: Were there any errors or warnings in `[pip output]` after `pip install numpy` on the server? Maybe it also shows you where it actually installed it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for the idea, but the output didn't seem helpful to me. I included the output in an edit above.

Comment: Check if there is an alias for `pip` set on the server

Comment: @FlyingTeller I just ran ```alias``` and got no alias for ```pip``` or any other python commands for that matter.